# Knowing who has a document checked out?

Tags: check-out

In SharePoint 2013 is there a way to know if another team member has a document checked out?

We have decided to not use co-authoring. My question sounds like co-authoring would be the solution. Would there be another way?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can easily identify if a document is checked out based on the green arrow icon 
[image: Checked Out Document]

To see *who* it is checked out to, you can do a couple things:

1. Add the "Checked Out to" column to your library. If a document is checked out, it will display the username in this column
2. If you hover over the green arrow icon, the tooltip will display the username of who the file is checked out to